# How to get hostname in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way where I can get hostname/servername in postgresql like @@ServerName in SQL Server?

Comment: Use a variation on this technique to run the OS hostname command https://serverfault.com/a/901196/58037

Answer (score 9):

You need to execute following query to get the hostname:

```
SELECT boot_val,reset_val
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name='listen_addresses';;
```

Comment: I have corrected my answer to get the hostname info directly from postgresql. However it will only display what is configured in **postgresql.conf**. In order to get accurate hostname of server one must check `hostname` command on shell.

Comment: Well, in my case that simply returns `localhost` ;)

Comment: This worked on my Windows 10 machine. Note I also used this link for help in order to connect pgadmin to the DB on my personal machine: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL doesn't provide a builtin function returning the server's hostname.

A `pg_gethostname()` function written in C (a wrapper to POSIX's `gethostname()`) has been contributed on the wiki and made available as an extension on PGXN:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pg_gethostname

https://pgxn.org/dist/hostname/

If you can't install that on the server, or an equivalent in another language supporting calls to the system such as plperlu or plpythonu, you're probably going to be limited to [inet_server_addr()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html).

Answer (score 5):

I use such a solution. No plugins required. Temporary tables are not needed. Only for unix.

```
select pg_read_file('/etc/hostname') as hostname;
```

Comment: This will only work for the database superuser.

Comment: Since this only works for the superuser, if you're on AWS RDS, you only have an admin account which is not the superuser, so this does not work at all / on rds.

Comment: @user1822: Not just only for superusers, but also not on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve this issue after creating a temp table and filling it with the result of  copy from

```
-- creating a temporary table and only one column
# CREATE TEMP TABLE tt_cmd (hostname text);
CREATE TABLE
-- filling the column with the result of the command
# COPY tt_cmd FROM PROGRAM 'hostname';
COPY 1
-- checking the result
# SELECT * from tt_cmd ;
+-------------+
|  hostname   |
+-------------+
| db_hostname |
+-------------+
-- filling the result into a variable
# SELECT * FROM tt_cmd \gset
-- no return
-- checking the result
# \echo :hostname
db_hostname
-- dropping the temporary table
DROP TABLE tt_cmd ;
DROP TABLE
-- the variable is still here with the right result
# \echo :hostname
db_hostname
```

And I can use the result like this, to check, for example, if I'm running on a production server.

```
SELECT CASE :'hostname' WHEN 'prod_db_hostname' THEN 'PROD/' ELSE '' END AS sub_dir
\gset
```

> After reading the comments, the answer is right if you're executing on Pg server. That's the case for me. Of course, the hostname result is where you're executing it.
> Maybe there's a way with `HOST` variable value using it in psql.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN :'HOST' ~* '^server_prod_hostname' THEN '/on_prod' ELSE '/offprod' END AS dir;
```

Comment: `\! hostname` returns hostname where the `psql` is running.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing, first you give the wrong advice `\! hostname` - return client hostname, and then you give the right answer.
This command does what is needed - `COPY tt_cmd (ret) FROM PROGRAM 'hostname';`

Comment: Sorry, I've check on a server, not a client. So, happy to know that the command is the right anwser.